# cin stream position

Tags: c++

I am counting the number of non-whitespace characters in the standard input stream (cin) using in.get(). For every character which is not a whitespace character, I increment a counter.

After I'm done counting, I'd like to go back and read the characters. in is a parameter of type std::istream& in (cin in this case).

Here's what I am trying:

```
std::streampos sp = in.tellg();

while(in)
{
    char c = in.peek();

    if(isspace(c))
        break;

    ++str.mSize;
    in.get();
}

in.seekg(sp);
```

The value of sp is -1 indicating failure. Why?

Comment: Why do you need to first know the count of non-whitespace characters and only then you can read from the stream? there might be a better solution to the general problem without this problem at all.

Comment: I need to dynamically allocate a buffer to hold the characters. I am trying to implement the solution without using STL containers.

Comment: by specification, `stdin` has access to only one character at a time - it cannot go back. you have to use STL containers or a homemade buffer which will probably be worse than STL.

Comment: Thanks Dani. It sounds like I would have to allocate an initial buffer to hold everything and then sort through it, and copy what I want into my second buffer. This doesn't sound very efficient but that is why STL containers exist, I guess. If I wanted to continue with this inefficient solution involving 2 homemade buffers, any idea how I would choose an appropriate size for the initial storage buffer?

Comment: first use a size of 1. every time you don't have enough space multiply the size by 2: 1,2,4,8,16 ...etc. that guarantees that the complexity of the allocation will not be higher than complexity of the buffering in average case. (in simple: it will not slow anything down too much).

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all input streams are seekable—if `stdin` is coming from a terminal or a pipe, it's not possible to seek it, forwards or backwards.  In that case, you have to buffer the data yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to implement a solution without using STL containers. I wanted to first count the number of consecutive non-whitespace characters so that I could dynamically allocate a buffer of the appropriate size to hold them. But I guess the only solution is to allocate two buffers. But in this case, I don't know how I would choose an appropriate size for my initial storage buffer.